# how to use .yaml files with ROSJava

Tags: ros, yaml, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

In a project, I would like to use .yaml files with a node developed with ROSJava.

Any help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12550/how-to-use-.yaml-files-with-rosjava/) by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 274 on 2012-01-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem using the following project:
http://code.google.com/p/yamlbeans/

In a first iteration, I used snakeYAML but yamlbeans is easier to process ROS yaml files.

---

Originally posted by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) with karma: 274 on 2012-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1